# Start with content in the middle of the first page

Tags: invoice

I try to create an invoice with latex. The first part with the header, address and so on is finished. But now my question.

How can I define the start on the text in the first sheet? The table should starts in the middle of the first sheet, and if the table reach the footer, the following lines should be on the text sheet.

I tried with a textblock, but in case of this the whole content is written on this page int the block and not on a new page.

Here an visual example

The issue, I`m talking about is the TABLE WITH DATA field.

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{showframe}
% Required for proper escaping
\usepackage{textcomp} % Symbols
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Input format
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, bottom=30mm, right=24mm, left=28mm }
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

% Fraben
\usepackage{color}

% Footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % no line in header area
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[C]{\footerText} % other info in "inner" position of footer line
\fancyfoot[R]{%
    \fontsize{2mm}{0mm} Seite \thepage\ von \pageref{LastPage}
}

\newcommand{\footerText}{
    \bf \fontsize{2mm}{3mm}\selectfont  Sound form out of space! \\
}

% Because Unicode etc.
\usepackage{fontspec} % For loading fonts
\setmainfont{Arial} % Has a lot more symbols than Computer Modern /Liberation Serif

% Make placeholders visible
\newcommand{\placeholder}[1]{\textbf{$<$ #1 $>$}}

% Helper Funktionen
\usepackage[overlay,absolute]{textpos}
\newcommand{\PlaceText}[3]{
    \begin{textblock*} {175mm}(#1,#2)  %% change width of box from 10in as you wish
        #3
    \end{textblock*}
}

\newcommand\tab[1][1cm]{\hspace*{#1}}


\newcommand{\signature}[1]{
    \fontsize{3mm}{3mm}\selectfont  #1
}


% Variablen und Funktionen

% Fill in - Setzen der Variablen aus PHP
% 
\newcommand{\rechnungsNr}{B 73 / 997.050}
% 
\newcommand{\rechnungsDatum}{26.05.2016}

%ABSENDER
% 
\newcommand{\absenderAdresseName}{Example Company}
% 
\newcommand{\absenderAdresseAnschrift}{Nowhere 42, 0815 Mars, Sun-System A}

%EMPFÄNGER
% 
\newcommand{\empfaengerAnrede}{Firma}
% 
\newcommand{\empfaengerAdresseName}{Target Company}
% 
\newcommand{\empfaengerAdresseAnschrift}{Moonroad 42}
% 
\newcommand{\empfaengerOrt}{9999 Earth}
% 
\newcommand{\empfaengerLand}{Sun-System A}

%LIEFERSCHEIN DATEN
% 
\newcommand{\liefNr}{101124}
% 
\newcommand{\uidNrLieferant}{XX59193388}
% 
\newcommand{\reklamationNr}{2288559}
% 
\newcommand{\reklamationDatum}{11.05.2016}
% 
\newcommand{\uidNrSdi}{YY125478}
% 
\newcommand{\unserZeichen}{Bob Dylan}
% 
\newcommand{\telefon}{}
% 
\newcommand{\email}{b.dylan@example.com}
% 
\newcommand{\auftNr}{Moon Sound Blues}
% 
\newcommand{\zahlKzUstKz}{Who cares...}

%ZAHLUNGSKONDITIONEN UND SUMMIERUNGEN
% 
\newcommand{\waehrung}{EUR}
% 
\newcommand{\netto}{55,00}
% 
\newcommand{\mwst}{20}
% 
\newcommand{\mwstBetrag}{11,00}
% 
\newcommand{\summe}{66,00}
% 
\newcommand{\unterschriftA}{Clapton}
% 
\newcommand{\unterschriftB}{Satriani}


\newcommand{\titleRechnung}{
    {
        \PlaceText{100mm}{24mm}
        {
            {
                \fontsize{8mm}{15mm}\selectfont \bf Rechnung
            }
        }
    }
}

\newcommand{\rechnungIdentification}[2]{
    {
        \PlaceText{100mm}{36mm}{\fontsize{5mm}{15mm}\selectfont \bf Nr. #1 vom #2}
    }
}


\newcommand{\absender}{
    \PlaceText{22mm}{35mm}{
        \absenderAdresseName \hfill \break
        \absenderAdresseAnschrift
    }
}

\newcommand{\empfaenger}{
    \PlaceText{22mm}{45mm}{
        \bf
        \empfaengerAnrede \hfill \break
        \empfaengerAdresseName\\
        \empfaengerAdresseAnschrift\\
        \MakeUppercase{\empfaengerOrt}\\
        \MakeUppercase{\empfaengerLand}\\
    }
}

\newcommand{\lieferscheinDaten}{
    \PlaceText{86mm}{45mm}{
        \fontsize{3mm}{4mm}\selectfont
        \begin{tabular}{l p{69mm}}
            \bf Lief Nr & \bf \liefNr \\
            \bf Reklamation &  \bf \reklamationNr\ von \reklamationDatum \\
            Telefon & \telefon \\
            Email & \email \\
            Auftr Nr & \auftNr \\
        \end{tabular}
    }
}


\newcommand{\demoListe}{
    \PlaceText{22mm}{128mm}{
        \begin{tabular}{|l|c|r|p{5cm}|}
            \hline
            ID & Vorname & Nachname & Adesse\\  \hline
            %
            1&Max&Mustermann&Hier\\ \hline
            2&Claudia&Musterfrau&Dort\\ \hline
            3&Armin&Gustavson&ganz wo anders\\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    }
}

\newcommand{\spaltenLabel}[1]{
    \bf \fontsize{4mm}{4mm}\selectfont #1
}

\newcommand{\spaltenWert}[1]{
    \fontsize{3mm}{4mm}\selectfont #1
}


\newcommand{\rechnungsListe}{
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \PlaceText{22mm}{128mm}{
        \begin{tabular}{l p{75mm} r r r r}
            \rowcolor{lightgray}
            \spaltenLabel{Pos.} & \spaltenLabel{Bezeichnung} & \spaltenLabel{Menge} & \spaltenLabel{Preis je} & \spaltenLabel{Einzelpreis} & \spaltenLabel{Betrag} \\
            \fontsize{2mm}{2mm}\selectfont
            %
            \spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 1}&\spaltenWert{1,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{1,00}&\spaltenWert{1,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{2}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 2}&\spaltenWert{2,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{2,00}&\spaltenWert{4,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{3}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 3}&\spaltenWert{3,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{3,00}&\spaltenWert{9,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{4}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 4}&\spaltenWert{4,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{4,00}&\spaltenWert{16,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{5}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 5}&\spaltenWert{5,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{5,00}&\spaltenWert{25,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{6}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 6}&\spaltenWert{1,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{1,00}&\spaltenWert{1,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{7}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 7}&\spaltenWert{2,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{2,00}&\spaltenWert{4,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{8}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 8}&\spaltenWert{3,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{3,00}&\spaltenWert{9,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{9}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 9}&\spaltenWert{4,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{4,00}&\spaltenWert{16,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{10}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 10}&\spaltenWert{5,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{5,00}&\spaltenWert{25,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{11}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 6}&\spaltenWert{1,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{1,00}&\spaltenWert{1,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{12}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 7}&\spaltenWert{2,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{2,00}&\spaltenWert{4,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{13}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 8}&\spaltenWert{3,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{3,00}&\spaltenWert{9,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{14}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 9}&\spaltenWert{4,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{4,00}&\spaltenWert{16,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{15}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 10}&\spaltenWert{5,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{5,00}&\spaltenWert{25,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{16}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 6}&\spaltenWert{1,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{1,00}&\spaltenWert{1,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{17}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 7}&\spaltenWert{2,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{2,00}&\spaltenWert{4,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{18}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 8}&\spaltenWert{3,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{3,00}&\spaltenWert{9,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{19}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 9}&\spaltenWert{4,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{4,00}&\spaltenWert{16,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{20}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 10}&\spaltenWert{5,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{5,00}&\spaltenWert{25,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{21}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 6}&\spaltenWert{1,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{1,00}&\spaltenWert{1,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{22}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 7}&\spaltenWert{2,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{2,00}&\spaltenWert{4,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{23}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 8}&\spaltenWert{3,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{3,00}&\spaltenWert{9,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{24}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 9}&\spaltenWert{4,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{4,00}&\spaltenWert{16,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{25}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 10}&\spaltenWert{5,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{5,00}&\spaltenWert{25,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{26}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 6}&\spaltenWert{1,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{1,00}&\spaltenWert{1,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{27}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 7}&\spaltenWert{2,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{2,00}&\spaltenWert{4,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{28}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 8}&\spaltenWert{3,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{3,00}&\spaltenWert{9,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{29}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 9}&\spaltenWert{4,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{4,00}&\spaltenWert{16,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{30}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 10}&\spaltenWert{5,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{5,00}&\spaltenWert{25,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{31}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 6}&\spaltenWert{1,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{1,00}&\spaltenWert{1,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{32}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 7}&\spaltenWert{2,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{2,00}&\spaltenWert{4,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{33}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 8}&\spaltenWert{3,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{3,00}&\spaltenWert{9,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{34}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 9}&\spaltenWert{4,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{4,00}&\spaltenWert{16,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{35}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 10}&\spaltenWert{5,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{5,00}&\spaltenWert{25,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{36}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 6}&\spaltenWert{1,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{1,00}&\spaltenWert{1,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{37}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 7}&\spaltenWert{2,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{2,00}&\spaltenWert{4,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{38}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 8}&\spaltenWert{3,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{3,00}&\spaltenWert{9,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{39}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 9}&\spaltenWert{4,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{4,00}&\spaltenWert{16,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{40}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 10}&\spaltenWert{5,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{5,00}&\spaltenWert{25,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{41}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 6}&\spaltenWert{1,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{1,00}&\spaltenWert{1,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{42}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 7}&\spaltenWert{2,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{2,00}&\spaltenWert{4,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{43}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 8}&\spaltenWert{3,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{3,00}&\spaltenWert{9,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{44}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 9}&\spaltenWert{4,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{4,00}&\spaltenWert{16,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{45}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 10}&\spaltenWert{5,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{5,00}&\spaltenWert{25,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{46}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 6}&\spaltenWert{1,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{1,00}&\spaltenWert{1,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{47}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 7}&\spaltenWert{2,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{2,00}&\spaltenWert{4,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{48}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 8}&\spaltenWert{3,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{3,00}&\spaltenWert{9,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{49}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 9}&\spaltenWert{4,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{4,00}&\spaltenWert{16,00}\\ 
            \spaltenWert{50}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 10}&\spaltenWert{5,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{5,00}&\spaltenWert{25,00}\\                \hline
        \end{tabular} \\
        \begin{tabular}{l l}
            \begin{minipage}{.2\linewidth}
                \begin{tabular}{l}
                    \bf \fontsize{3mm}{3mm}{Zahlungskonditionen} \\
                    %
                    \spaltenWert{sofort, ohne Abzug}\\ 
                    \spaltenWert{weitere Optionen}\\                             \bf \fontsize{3mm}{3mm}{Währung: } \waehrung \\
                \end{tabular}
            \end{minipage} &
            \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
                \begin{tabular}{p{30mm} l p{30mm} r}
                    \fontsize{3mm}{3mm} & {\bf Nettobetrag: } & & \bf \netto \\
                    \fontsize{3mm}{3mm} & {\bf \mwst \% MWSt.: } & & \bf \mwstBetrag \\
                    \fontsize{3mm}{3mm} & {\bf Rechnungsbetrag(DEBIT): } & & \bf \summe \\
                \end{tabular}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{tabular}


        \hfill \bf XY SOUND MAKER \\
        \\
        \\
        \\

        \hfill \signature{\unterschriftA} \tab \tab \tab \tab \signature{\unterschriftB}
    }
}


% ------ DOCUMENT -------
\begin{document}
    \textcolor{white}{text}
    %Die erste Zeile ist nötig um das Zählen der Seiten zu unterstützen. Aktuell noch keine passende Lösung gefunden.
    \titleRechnung{}
    \rechnungIdentification{\rechnungsNr}{\rechnungsDatum}
    \absender{}
    \empfaenger{}
    \lieferscheinDaten
    \vspace*{90mm}

    %        \PlaceText{22mm}{128mm}{
    \begin{tabular}{l p{75mm} r r r r}
        \rowcolor{lightgray}
        \spaltenLabel{Pos.} & \spaltenLabel{Bezeichnung} & \spaltenLabel{Menge} & \spaltenLabel{Preis je} & \spaltenLabel{Einzelpreis} & \spaltenLabel{Betrag} \\
        \fontsize{2mm}{2mm}\selectfont
        %
        \spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 1}&\spaltenWert{1,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{1,00}&\spaltenWert{1,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{2}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 2}&\spaltenWert{2,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{2,00}&\spaltenWert{4,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{3}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 3}&\spaltenWert{3,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{3,00}&\spaltenWert{9,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{4}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 4}&\spaltenWert{4,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{4,00}&\spaltenWert{16,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{5}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 5}&\spaltenWert{5,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{5,00}&\spaltenWert{25,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{6}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 6}&\spaltenWert{1,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{1,00}&\spaltenWert{1,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{7}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 7}&\spaltenWert{2,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{2,00}&\spaltenWert{4,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{8}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 8}&\spaltenWert{3,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{3,00}&\spaltenWert{9,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{9}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 9}&\spaltenWert{4,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{4,00}&\spaltenWert{16,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{10}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 10}&\spaltenWert{5,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{5,00}&\spaltenWert{25,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{11}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 6}&\spaltenWert{1,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{1,00}&\spaltenWert{1,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{12}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 7}&\spaltenWert{2,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{2,00}&\spaltenWert{4,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{13}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 8}&\spaltenWert{3,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{3,00}&\spaltenWert{9,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{14}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 9}&\spaltenWert{4,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{4,00}&\spaltenWert{16,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{15}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 10}&\spaltenWert{5,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{5,00}&\spaltenWert{25,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{16}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 6}&\spaltenWert{1,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{1,00}&\spaltenWert{1,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{17}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 7}&\spaltenWert{2,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{2,00}&\spaltenWert{4,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{18}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 8}&\spaltenWert{3,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{3,00}&\spaltenWert{9,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{19}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 9}&\spaltenWert{4,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{4,00}&\spaltenWert{16,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{20}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 10}&\spaltenWert{5,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{5,00}&\spaltenWert{25,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{21}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 6}&\spaltenWert{1,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{1,00}&\spaltenWert{1,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{22}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 7}&\spaltenWert{2,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{2,00}&\spaltenWert{4,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{23}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 8}&\spaltenWert{3,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{3,00}&\spaltenWert{9,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{24}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 9}&\spaltenWert{4,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{4,00}&\spaltenWert{16,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{25}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 10}&\spaltenWert{5,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{5,00}&\spaltenWert{25,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{26}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 6}&\spaltenWert{1,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{1,00}&\spaltenWert{1,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{27}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 7}&\spaltenWert{2,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{2,00}&\spaltenWert{4,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{28}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 8}&\spaltenWert{3,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{3,00}&\spaltenWert{9,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{29}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 9}&\spaltenWert{4,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{4,00}&\spaltenWert{16,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{30}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 10}&\spaltenWert{5,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{5,00}&\spaltenWert{25,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{31}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 6}&\spaltenWert{1,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{1,00}&\spaltenWert{1,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{32}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 7}&\spaltenWert{2,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{2,00}&\spaltenWert{4,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{33}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 8}&\spaltenWert{3,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{3,00}&\spaltenWert{9,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{34}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 9}&\spaltenWert{4,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{4,00}&\spaltenWert{16,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{35}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 10}&\spaltenWert{5,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{5,00}&\spaltenWert{25,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{36}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 6}&\spaltenWert{1,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{1,00}&\spaltenWert{1,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{37}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 7}&\spaltenWert{2,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{2,00}&\spaltenWert{4,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{38}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 8}&\spaltenWert{3,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{3,00}&\spaltenWert{9,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{39}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 9}&\spaltenWert{4,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{4,00}&\spaltenWert{16,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{40}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 10}&\spaltenWert{5,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{5,00}&\spaltenWert{25,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{41}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 6}&\spaltenWert{1,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{1,00}&\spaltenWert{1,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{42}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 7}&\spaltenWert{2,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{2,00}&\spaltenWert{4,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{43}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 8}&\spaltenWert{3,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{3,00}&\spaltenWert{9,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{44}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 9}&\spaltenWert{4,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{4,00}&\spaltenWert{16,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{45}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 10}&\spaltenWert{5,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{5,00}&\spaltenWert{25,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{46}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 6}&\spaltenWert{1,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{1,00}&\spaltenWert{1,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{47}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 7}&\spaltenWert{2,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{2,00}&\spaltenWert{4,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{48}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 8}&\spaltenWert{3,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{3,00}&\spaltenWert{9,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{49}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 9}&\spaltenWert{4,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{4,00}&\spaltenWert{16,00}\\ 
        \spaltenWert{50}&\spaltenWert{Demoartikel 10}&\spaltenWert{5,0}&\spaltenWert{1}&\spaltenWert{5,00}&\spaltenWert{25,00}\\                    \hline
    \end{tabular} \\
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
        \begin{minipage}{.2\linewidth}
            \begin{tabular}{l}
                \bf \fontsize{3mm}{3mm}{Zahlungskonditionen} \\
                %
                \spaltenWert{sofort, ohne Abzug}\\ 
                \spaltenWert{weitere Optionen}\\                                 \bf \fontsize{3mm}{3mm}{Währung: } \waehrung \\
            \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage} &
        \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
            \begin{tabular}{p{30mm} l p{36mm} r}
                \fontsize{3mm}{3mm} & {\bf Nettobetrag: } & & \bf \netto \\
                \fontsize{3mm}{3mm} & {\bf \mwst \% MWSt.: } & & \bf \mwstBetrag \\
                 \\
            \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{tabular}


    \hfill \bf SIGN HERE\\
    \\
    \\
    \\

    \hfill \signature{\unterschriftA} \tab \tab \tab \tab \signature{\unterschriftB}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you add a MWE so we can visualize it and see the details?

Comment: Have you tried something like`\vspace*{5cm}`? If the empty vertical space appears after the first paragraph of text, use `\par\vspace*{5cm}` instead.

Comment: @gernot yes I've tried, but by using \vspace*{??cm} the content runs over the footer and does not continue on the next page.

Comment: This is not the normal behaviour of a plain document, so please provide the code of a sample document (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) that illustrates your problem. Otherwise it is pure guessing, with little chance of success.

Comment: Do you use an environment like `\begin{longtable}...\end{longtable}` for your table so it is breakable accross several pages?

Comment: @gernot there was no other way to post it. so here is a link to the file https://goo.gl/oMz6Rf

Comment: Oh yes, there is a way ;-) ... the edit button, see above.

Comment: @gernot well... convinced :)

Comment: It is not really surprising that your document does not break across pages: The `tabular` environment does not break, and even if it would, you wrap it into a `textblock` which makes unbreakable whatever you put into it.

Comment: Give me a minute ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `xtab` package, for tables that break across pages. Some more (unasked for) advice:

- Don't use `\bf`, but `{\bfseries ...}` or `\textbf{...}`.
- Try to do without absolute positioning. You might want to position the recipient's address at a certain position, to fit envelopes with address windows. By typesetting the material above the address properly it is also possible to place it correctly. Just ask again if you don't know how to do it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% Either use this (with any latex, under any OS)
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% or this (with xelatex and lualatex, under Windows)
% \usepackage{fontspec} % For loading fonts
% \setmainfont{Arial} % Has a lot more symbols than Computer Modern /Liberation Serif

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, bottom=30mm, right=24mm, left=28mm }
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

% Farben
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

% Seitenfuß
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % no line in header area
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[C]{\footerText} % other info in "inner" position of footer line
\fancyfoot[R]{\footnotesize Seite \thepage\ von \pageref{LastPage}}
\newcommand{\footerText}{\bfseries\footnotesize Sound form out of space!}

% Tabellen, die umbrechen
\usepackage{xtab}

%ABSENDER
\newcommand\absenderAdresseName{Example Company}
\newcommand\absenderAdresseAnschrift{Nowhere 42, 0815 Mars, Sun-System A}

%EMPFÄNGER
\newcommand\empfaengerAnrede{Firma}
\newcommand\empfaengerAdresseName{Target Company}
\newcommand\empfaengerAdresseAnschrift{Moonroad 42}
\newcommand\empfaengerOrt{9999 Earth}
\newcommand\empfaengerLand{Sun-System A}

%TITEL
\newcommand\titleRechnung{Rechnung}
\newcommand\rechnungIdentification[2]{Nr.~#1 vom #2}
\newcommand\rechnungsNr{B 73 / 997.050}
\newcommand\rechnungsDatum{26.05.2016}

%LIEFERSCHEIN DATEN
\newcommand\liefNr{101124}
\newcommand\uidNrLieferant{XX59193388}
\newcommand\reklamationNr{2288559}
\newcommand\reklamationDatum{11.05.2016}
\newcommand\uidNrSdi{YY125478}
\newcommand\unserZeichen{Bob Dylan}
\newcommand\telefon{}
\newcommand\email{b.dylan@example.com}
\newcommand\auftNr{Moon Sound Blues}
\newcommand\zahlKzUstKz{Who cares...}

%ZAHLUNGSKONDITIONEN UND SUMMIERUNGEN
\newcommand\waehrung{EUR}
\newcommand\netto{55,00}
\newcommand\mwst{20}
\newcommand\mwstBetrag{11,00}
\newcommand\summe{66,00}
\newcommand\unterschriftA{Clapton}
\newcommand\unterschriftB{Satriani}

\newcommand\makeheader
 {\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \absenderAdresseName\\
    \absenderAdresseAnschrift
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.55\textwidth}
    \bfseries\LARGE
    \titleRechnung\\
    {\Large\rechnungIdentification{\rechnungsNr}{\rechnungsDatum}}
  \end{minipage}%
  \par\bigskip
  {\bfseries
   \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
     \empfaengerAnrede\\
     \empfaengerAdresseName\\
     \empfaengerAdresseAnschrift\\
     \MakeUppercase{\empfaengerOrt}\\
     \MakeUppercase{\empfaengerLand}
   \end{tabular}%
  }%
  \hfill
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}ll@{}}
    \bfseries Lief Nr     & \bfseries \liefNr       \\
    \bfseries Reklamation & \bfseries \reklamationNr\\
    Telefon               & \telefon                \\
    Email                 & \email                  \\
    Auftr Nr              & \auftNr
  \end{tabular}%
  \par\vspace*{3cm}
}

\newcommand\makefooter
  {\par\vspace{1cm}
   \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
     {\bfseries Zahlungskonditionen}\\
     sofort, ohne Abzug\\
     weitere Optionen\\
     {\bfseries Währung:} \waehrung
   \end{minipage}%
   \hfill
   {\bfseries
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{\quad}r@{}}
      Nettobetrag:    & \netto\\
      \mwst \% MWSt.: & \mwstBetrag
    \end{tabular}%
    \par\bigskip
    \hspace*{\fill}SIGN HERE
    \par\vspace{2cm}
    \hspace*{\fill}\unterschriftA\hspace*{3cm}\unterschriftB
   }%
  }

\begin{document}
\makeheader

\tablehead
  {\rowcolor{lightgray}\bfseries Pos. & \bfseries Bezeichnung &
   \bfseries Menge & \bfseries Preis je & \bfseries Einzelpreis & \bfseries Betrag \\
  }
\let\tablefirsthead\tablehead
\let\tablelasthead\tablehead
\begin{xtabular}{l p{68mm} r r r r}
   1 & Demoartikel 1 & 1,0 & 1 & 1,00 & 1,00 \\ 
   2 & Demoartikel 2 & 2,0 & 1 & 2,00 & 4,00 \\ 
   3 & Demoartikel 3 & 3,0 & 1 & 3,00 & 9,00 \\ 
   4 & Demoartikel 4 & 4,0 & 1 & 4,00 & 16,00 \\ 
   5 & Demoartikel 5 & 5,0 & 1 & 5,00 & 25,00 \\ 
   6 & Demoartikel 6 & 1,0 & 1 & 1,00 & 1,00 \\ 
   7 & Demoartikel 7 & 2,0 & 1 & 2,00 & 4,00 \\ 
   8 & Demoartikel 8 & 3,0 & 1 & 3,00 & 9,00 \\ 
   9 & Demoartikel 9 & 4,0 & 1 & 4,00 & 16,00 \\ 
  10 & Demoartikel 10 & 5,0 & 1 & 5,00 & 25,00 \\ 
  11 & Demoartikel 6 & 1,0 & 1 & 1,00 & 1,00 \\ 
  12 & Demoartikel 7 & 2,0 & 1 & 2,00 & 4,00 \\ 
  13 & Demoartikel 8 & 3,0 & 1 & 3,00 & 9,00 \\ 
  14 & Demoartikel 9 & 4,0 & 1 & 4,00 & 16,00 \\ 
  15 & Demoartikel 10 & 5,0 & 1 & 5,00 & 25,00 \\ 
  16 & Demoartikel 6 & 1,0 & 1 & 1,00 & 1,00 \\ 
  17 & Demoartikel 7 & 2,0 & 1 & 2,00 & 4,00 \\ 
  18 & Demoartikel 8 & 3,0 & 1 & 3,00 & 9,00 \\ 
  19 & Demoartikel 9 & 4,0 & 1 & 4,00 & 16,00 \\ 
  20 & Demoartikel 10 & 5,0 & 1 & 5,00 & 25,00 \\ 
  21 & Demoartikel 6 & 1,0 & 1 & 1,00 & 1,00 \\ 
  22 & Demoartikel 7 & 2,0 & 1 & 2,00 & 4,00 \\ 
  23 & Demoartikel 8 & 3,0 & 1 & 3,00 & 9,00 \\ 
  24 & Demoartikel 9 & 4,0 & 1 & 4,00 & 16,00 \\ 
  25 & Demoartikel 10 & 5,0 & 1 & 5,00 & 25,00 \\ 
  26 & Demoartikel 6 & 1,0 & 1 & 1,00 & 1,00 \\ 
  27 & Demoartikel 7 & 2,0 & 1 & 2,00 & 4,00 \\ 
  28 & Demoartikel 8 & 3,0 & 1 & 3,00 & 9,00 \\ 
  29 & Demoartikel 9 & 4,0 & 1 & 4,00 & 16,00 \\ 
  30 & Demoartikel 10 & 5,0 & 1 & 5,00 & 25,00 \\ 
  31 & Demoartikel 6 & 1,0 & 1 & 1,00 & 1,00 \\ 
  32 & Demoartikel 7 & 2,0 & 1 & 2,00 & 4,00 \\ 
  33 & Demoartikel 8 & 3,0 & 1 & 3,00 & 9,00 \\ 
  34 & Demoartikel 9 & 4,0 & 1 & 4,00 & 16,00 \\ 
  35 & Demoartikel 10 & 5,0 & 1 & 5,00 & 25,00 \\ 
  36 & Demoartikel 6 & 1,0 & 1 & 1,00 & 1,00 \\ 
  37 & Demoartikel 7 & 2,0 & 1 & 2,00 & 4,00 \\ 
  38 & Demoartikel 8 & 3,0 & 1 & 3,00 & 9,00 \\ 
  39 & Demoartikel 9 & 4,0 & 1 & 4,00 & 16,00 \\ 
  40 & Demoartikel 10 & 5,0 & 1 & 5,00 & 25,00 \\ 
  41 & Demoartikel 6 & 1,0 & 1 & 1,00 & 1,00 \\ 
  42 & Demoartikel 7 & 2,0 & 1 & 2,00 & 4,00 \\ 
  43 & Demoartikel 8 & 3,0 & 1 & 3,00 & 9,00 \\ 
  44 & Demoartikel 9 & 4,0 & 1 & 4,00 & 16,00 \\ 
  45 & Demoartikel 10 & 5,0 & 1 & 5,00 & 25,00 \\ 
  46 & Demoartikel 6 & 1,0 & 1 & 1,00 & 1,00 \\ 
  47 & Demoartikel 7 & 2,0 & 1 & 2,00 & 4,00 \\ 
  48 & Demoartikel 8 & 3,0 & 1 & 3,00 & 9,00 \\ 
  49 & Demoartikel 9 & 4,0 & 1 & 4,00 & 16,00 \\ 
  50 & Demoartikel 10 & 5,0 & 1 & 5,00 & 25,00 
\end{xtabular}

\makefooter
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes.. you made my day !! :)